# Creating a GUI using Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to create user interfaces using the Qt framework without utilizing the Qt Creator program? It seems that when using this program half of the work must be done by you anyway, so why not learn how it works more fundamentally (insofar as the Qt API is concerned) and implement the programs yourself?

It seems that Qt implements XML files and does a lot of heavy lifting for you when using the creator program (i.e. automatically including class member functions, etc). I have previously implemented GUIs in Java and did not have to dabble in XML. Does Java handle this behind the scenes, or does Qt approach the problem differently?

Comment: Although knowing how your framework works is important, whenever you are doing any GUI slightly more complicated than a hello world the designer is going to save you a lot of hassle. Also, I don't see how "half the must be done by you anyway", probably you are missing how to use some feature (e.g. the fundamental "go to slot" command, hidden halfway through a context menu).

Comment: You should not have to edit the XML files at all. You should be editing the UI files using QtDesigner, which is embedded into QtCreator.

Answer (score 4):

Qt has more than way to create a GUI. There is the old QtWidgets module which works with "classical" desktop UI widgets and has a C++ API. The XML file is just a convenient way to describe your interface, qmake will generate C++ headers from the XMLs and generate a lot of the boilerplate for you.
If you prefer, you can do all the work yourself entirely in C++ by instantiating the various `QWidget` subclasses (`QMainWindow`, `QLabel`, etc.) and using their APIs.

(I'm not familiar enough with Java to answer that part of the question.)

However, I suggest you to **take a look at Qt Quick** which allows for a better and more modern way to deal with GUIs, and gives you a lot more freedom. (It's also a lot easier and faster to work with.)

If you want more details on either of them, just write a comment :)

Comment: To add to Venemo's answer, here's an old official tutorial that shows you how to write widget-based GUIs in pure C++: http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.3/tutorial.html ...and here's a new official tutorial that shows you how to write Qt Quick GUIs in pure QML: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. I am not going to make any statement on what is the best way because I do not even know how to use Qt Creator. Personally, I just use a text editor to create the source files. I have done that for ten years. I also agree with you on understanding API and structuring of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here's the code for how to create a simple window and a button.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QPushButton *quitButton = new QPushButton("Quit", 0);

  connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), &app, SLOT(quit()));

  return 0;
}
```

A good Qt tutorial:

http://meetingcpp.com/index.php/br/items/an-introduction-into-qt-part-ii.html

Answer (score 0):

QtCreator, if using g++ compiler:
When there are errors in code, allow right-click on errors list then *Show Outputs* (O shortcut)… and you can see g++ command with all options:

```
 g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../my-project -I. -I../../../anaconda3/include/qt -I../../../anaconda3/include/qt/QtWidgets -I../../../anaconda3/include/qt/QtGui -I../../../anaconda3/include/qt/QtCore -I. -I. -I../../../anaconda3/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o mainwindow.o ../my-project/mainwindow.cpp
```

So it only creates a *MakeFile* in *build-your-project-title-Debug* (or Release). If you edit it, you have all informations:

```
MAKEFILE      = Makefile

####### Compiler, tools and options

CC            = gcc
CXX           = g++
DEFINES       = -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB
CFLAGS        = -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -g -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I../sans_titre -I. -I../../../anaconda3/include/qt -I../../../anaconda3/include/qt/QtWidgets -I../../../anaconda3/include/qt/QtGui -I../../../anaconda3/include/qt/QtCore -I. -I. -I../../../anaconda3/mkspecs/linux-g++
…
```

You can reproduce it or just use QtCreator to define this MakeFile first then run under CLI with:

```
make
```